# Errors running tests using Angular v13 + Jest + ESM + NGXS

Tags: jest-preset-angular

The migration from Angular v12 to v13 has been tough and while the app functions perfectly, the tests are still a problem on our side.

We have been running v12 tests using Jest with ESM (because we have a WebWorker and the `import.meta.url` requires ESM since v12) successfully as of now.

But now that v13 ships with only ES Modules it breaks in some third party libraries requiring angular code.

Now that the `jest-preset-angular` supports running `v13 + ESM` with a working example [app](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/1222) I thought I'd give it another try. This is also being discussed in NGXS's [slack](https://ngxs.slack.com/archives/C016CNBQ16H/p1640441024021700).

My current very basic config is the following:

```js
const {pathsToModuleNameMapper} = require('ts-jest/utils');
const {paths} = require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions;
require('jest-preset-angular')

const esModules = ['tslib'].join('|');

/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular/presets/defaults-esm',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            useESM: true,
            stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig-esm.spec.json',
        },
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        ...pathsToModuleNameMapper(paths, {prefix: '<rootDir>'}),
        tslib: 'tslib/tslib.es6.js',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
};
```

I've gone through the documentation multiple times, I'm following migration issues being opened on different repo trying to address the issue.
I've also gone through the latest related issues including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088413/jest-preset-angular-not-working-with-angular-13-and-esm-module).

Has anyone managed to have a working `v13 + Jest + ESM + NGXS` stack ? I can't seem to figure it out.

*For anyone who wants to fidget with a minimal reproduction repo, you can find it [here](https://github.com/jbpzen/angular13-jest-esm-ngxs-test). The tests run fine without ESM and fail using ESM because we end up trying to `require` @angular from the NGXS bundle*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make it work while preserving the `import.meta.url` syntax with Jest which requires Node to be run with the `--experimental-vm-modules` flag.

I noticed that I could run my test using a classic ESM config as long as the node flag wasn't there.

So I resorted to transforming the `import.meta.url` syntax back to CommonJS in my test config using this babel [plugin](https://github.com/javiertury/babel-plugin-transform-import-meta)